# Can search return terms with both 'and' and 'ampersand' in the title?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results

In our farm we have departments setup in the term store that often have either an **ampersand (&)** or **and** in the title. However, when searching only the first defined term is being returned within search results. For example the department "*IT Systems & Services*" can be searched for and found by typing "*IT Systems **&** Services*" into the search box but **will not** be found by typing "*IT Systems **and** Services*"! I know excluding both will return the correct results but our users often search for the full term!

In the term store I've added an additional label to the term for "*IT Systems and Services*" and run a full search crawl but it still will not appear when searched.

Is there a way that we can get both variations searchable to return the correct term?

---

*Sorry if I have not used the correct terminology here, I'm struggling to find the correct terms to describe the situation we've encountered. Let me know if more details are required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless  what language do you use to search kql or Fql

Your main problem is you are including an **"and"** (an special word for searching engines) in the query, there are a lot of chances that word is dropped in the tokenization phase.

The search engine could drop the token **"and"** in order to exclude the possibility to mistake the searched word with a logical AND, the same happens with the **"OR"**

"Red **and** Blue" returns only the document with both words.

Unless you configured you search and build a custom query the result set returned won't included you expected document

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163973.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I'm just using default search components in SP2013. So i'm guessing KQL? I thought this might be the case. If the "and" token were dropped then should that not find results on "IT Systems Services"? And should a query of "IT Systems and Services" not return the correct department as it does indeed contain both terms? I'm sorry I quite new to the search component!

Comment: My understanding is "and" lowercase is a noise word in a query. "AND" uppercase is a logical Query term.